# OnePage CheckOut Magento2

Tags: magento2, onepage-checkout

I am new to M2 so please bear with me. 
I have purchased a theme "Ultimo 2" the problem is that on the demo theme on checkout it goes to /checkout/onepage. I have installed this theme on my local but on the checkout I only have 2 steps Shipping and Review and it redirect to /checkout page not on **/checkout/onpage**

Can anyone suggest what is wrong? I have checked the admin panel and set OnePage to Yes in the Cart option.

**Onepage Checkout**

[image: Onepage checkout] 
**My Checkout page**

[image: My checkout]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is onepage checkout in Magento 2 (a new look), the one that you're referring to as **Onepage Checkout** is M1's onepage checkout.

Comment: Thanks for answer so Magento2 checkout is very different than Magento2? I am wondering how few themes have same layout as M1

Comment: Yes M2 has completely different checkout as compared to M1. There are one step checkout extensions you can use if you don't want the default checkout e.g. https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-one-step-checkout-extension/